# Error in metadata: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause)

Tags: hadoop, metadata, hive, apache-pig

I have created a external table in hive and when I provide the location of the data for this table I get the following error:

FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Also I am able to load the same file using PIG Script using the PigStorage() loader function.

I have the following permissions on the file: rw-rw-r-
and on the folder where this file resides (Giving the path of this folder in location in the query ) : drwxrwxr-x

What can be the cause for this and how to correct this error ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have **write permission** on the file....

Comment: Is there a way I can change this permission issue by configuring HIVE because I can only have read access on the file.
Please HELP !

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this issue is having your `LOCATION` wrong for your hive table (in case someone else has this issue and can't figure out what is going wrong).